# Filename containing superstring causes gsutil error

Tags: utf-8, google-cloud-storage

I have a script I run from terminal, uploading files with gsutil in Centos 7, I receive an error about one of my file names.

```
Caught non-retryable exception while listing file:///home//:
CommandException: Invalid Unicode path encountered
('/home/mysite/public_html/images/office-100-m\xe2\xb2.jpg').
```

I checked in python like this (notice the superstring):

```
>>> "office-100-m²-2.jpg".decode("utf-8")
u'office-100-m\xb2-2.jpg'
```

It decodes? I was expecting to see an error. When I checked locale

```
python -c "import locale; print locale.getdefaultlocale()"
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
```

So what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

That string is not a valid unicode sequence. If you take the bytes and try to **decode** it, you'll see the error:

```
>>> s = '/home/mysite/public_html/images/office-100-m\xe2\xb2.jpg'
>>> s.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 44-45: invalid continuation byte
```

Similarly, if you **encode** the unicode string you have in your question, the encoded bytes are different from what's shown in the error. This is the correct utf-8 encoded version of that string:

```
>>> u"office-100-m²-2.jpg".encode('utf-8')
'office-100-m\xc2\xb2-2.jpg'
```

Notice `\xc2\xb2` vs. `\xe2\xb2`. I'm not sure what encoding your filesystem filename is, but it doesn't appear to be UTF-8.

Comment: Is there a command to list what encoding my filesystem is using? Or is it file by file basis? (this is using the default centos 7 image from what google compute engine offers during setup)